# Is there a way that I can compare an array and an arraylist?

Tags: java

Is there a way that I can compare an array and an arraylist like

```
if (array[0]==arraylist[0])
```

I am working on this problem:

```
String[] s= {"a","a","b","b","b","c"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
// create a new arraylist that stores the frequency of each character. 
// For example, "a" appears twice in s, so newArrayList[0]=2; "b" appears 
// three times, so newArrayList[1]=3, and so on.
```

My idea is using a loop to scan through the string array and every time when a letter in it equals the letter in list, int count++. But I dont know how to compare things in an array and things in an arraylist.

Comment: You are a bit vague about what the comparison should be. Is it just an equals? Or to you want to know something more specific.

Comment: You can't even compare two arrays that way (at least not meaningfully).

Comment: Why are you mixing arrays and array lists to begin with?  It's certainly *possible* to compare the two together, but one would generally avoid mixing and matching their data structures in this manner.

Comment: Do you *have* to use an arraylist to store the frequency? Hashmap would be much better for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate through the array and arraylist and compare elements. ArrayList elements are accessed with `.get(index)`. And if you are comparing Objects (non-primitives), you need to use the `.equals()` method, not `==`.

```
if(array[i].equals(arrayList.get(i) ) )
```

Answer (score 5):

Shortest way is this

```
Arrays.asList(arr).equals(list)
```

Comment: And not far off the fastest too

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayAndArrayListElementsComparison {
    public static int compareArrayAndArrayListElements(String[] array, ArrayList<String> arraylist) {
        int count = 0;
        for (String s : array) {
            if (arraylist.contains(s)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"};
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("");
        arraylist.add("a");
        arraylist.add("b");
        arraylist.add("c");

        if (!arraylist.isEmpty() && array.length > 0) {
            if (compareArrayAndArrayListElements(array, arraylist) == array.length) {
                System.out.println("ArrayList contains all the elements in Array");
            } else if (compareArrayAndArrayListElements(array, arraylist) > 0) {
                System.out.println("ArrayList contains only few elements in Array");
            } else {
                System.out.println("ArrayList contains none of the elements in Array");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Either ArrayList or Array is Empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You try

```
if (array[0].equals(arraylist[0]))
```

As in java comparisons string should use equals(). It's not like javascript.

Comment: arraylist[0] isn't going to work... Do you mean arraylist.get(0)?